# assigning weights to variables according to rankings

Tags: statistics

I have a survey results from 500 experts, regarding their opinion of the influence of certain variables on a dependent variable. Each of the experts ranked each variable (about 50 variables) in a scale between (-5) to 5, where (-5) implies a strong negative influence, 5 implies a strong positive influence and rank 0 means no influence. From these rankings I would like to create a weight for each variable. That is, to create 50 weights. Since ranking can be positive or negative, a regular mean doesn't feel right. I considered taking the mean of the absolute values, but then I miss the negative influences. I've also searched in the literature and didn't find much. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If by "weight" you mean average ranking, then the numerical average (mean) is what you want. If it turns out negative for some variable that variable has negative influence on average.

Comment: Thanks. My next step is to perform K-means with these 50 variables, and then to assign an index to each group of the K groups. This index will be based on the weights, and my intention is to compare between groups according to the index. I think that with regular average, the comparison between groups may provide false results.